# Can't use "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" when creating Postgres tables on Dbeaver?

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment, identity-column

I am using Dbeaver to create a Postgres database table but am getting a syntax error when using "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" for my incremented id value. It is strange because I used the exact same syntax when creating the table on my localhost and had no problem with any syntax errors or creating the table.

This is the SQL preview I have when attempting to save the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.conversation (
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    startdatetime timestamptz NOT NULL,
    enddatetime timestamptz NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT conversation_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

When I try to save the table, I get "ERROR: syntax error at or near 'GENERATED'". I thought this was correct syntax considering the SQL is built by Dbeaver itself and it worked fine when creating a local database to test on?

Comment: What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
 PostgreSQL 9.5.17 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

Comment: Identity columns were introduced in Postgres 10, you can't use them in (the somewhat outdated) Postgres 9.5

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so what should I do as an alternative?

Comment: Upgrade? Or use a `serial` as Gordon showed

Comment: So will the type be serial in other tables that reference the id as well?

Comment: no, that would be regular integer - just like with the identity column

Answer (score 2):

Just use `bigserial`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.conversation (
    id bigserial primary key,
    startdatetime timestamptz NOT NULL,
    enddatetime timestamptz NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: a `bigserial` behaves a bit different to a `generated always as identity`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . They are similar enough if for some reason the OP cannot use `generated always as identity`.

Comment: absolutely, that's why I suggested to use it in my comments to the question itself. I just wanted to point out, that there are slight differences.